# i need sql query to get the start and stop datetime of secondary power source

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the Generator Meter Data

| Sno | TIMESTAMP | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-08-22 19:56:00.010 | 10837 |
| 2 | 2023-08-22 19:57:00.013 | 10837 |
| 3 | 2023-08-22 19:58:00.010 | 10837 |
| 4 | 2023-08-22 19:59:00.123 | 10840 |
| 5 | 2023-08-22 20:00:00.347 | 10840 |
| 6 | 2023-08-22 20:01:00.563 | 10841 |
| 7 | 2023-08-22 20:02:00.953 | 10842 |
| 8 | 2023-08-22 20:03:00.007 | 10842 |
| 9 | 2023-08-22 20:04:00.003 | 10843 |
| 10 | 2023-08-22 20:05:00.017 | 10843 |
| 11 | 2023-08-22 20:06:00.007 | 10844 |
| 12 | 2023-08-22 20:07:00.000 | 10844 |
| 13 | 2023-08-22 20:08:00.017 | 10845 |
| 14 | 2023-08-22 20:09:00.003 | 10845 |
| 15 | 2023-08-22 20:10:00.030 | 10846 |
| 16 | 2023-08-22 20:11:00.017 | 10846 |
| 17 | 2023-08-22 20:12:00.013 | 10847 |
| 22 | 2023-08-22 20:13:00.020 | 10848 |
| 23 | 2023-08-22 20:14:00.010 | 10848 |
| 24 | 2023-08-22 20:15:00.013 | 10849 |
| 25 | 2023-08-22 20:16:00.093 | 10849 |
| 26 | 2023-08-22 20:17:00.297 | 10849 |
| 27 | 2023-08-22 20:18:00.557 | 10849 |
| 28 | 2023-08-23 21:22:00.823 | 10849 |
| 29 | 2023-08-23 21:23:00.823 | 10850 |
| 30 | 2023-08-23 21:24:00.823 | 10851 |
| 31 | 2023-08-23 21:25:00.823 | 10852 |
| 32 | 2023-08-23 21:26:00.823 | 10853 |
| 33 | 2023-08-23 21:27:00.823 | 10854 |
| 34 | 2023-08-23 21:28:00.823 | 10854 |
| 35 | 2023-08-23 21:29:00.823 | 10855 |
| 36 | 2023-08-23 21:30:00.823 | 10855 |
| 37 | 2023-08-23 21:31:00.823 | 10855 |
| 38 | 2023-08-23 21:32:00.823 | 10855 |
| 39 | 2023-08-23 21:33:00.823 | 10855 |
| 40 | 2023-08-23 21:34:00.823 | 10855 |

This is the generator meter data. As soon as the value changes, it means that the generator has been turned on. I need its time as the start time (when the value 10837 turned to 10840 as per data). And as soon as the time stops changing, and no changes occur for the next 10 rows or 10 minutes, I need the time at which the change stopped as the stop time.

If we look at the data, at "2023-08-22 19:59:00.123" the 4th Row is the start time and at "2023-08-22 20:15:00.013" the 24th row is the stop time (Because I am seeing the next 3 values the same).

it started again at "2023-08-23 21:22:00.823" the 29th row and stop at "2023-08-23 21:22:00.823" the 35th row

Tried many ways but unable to achieve the desired result.

Result should be

| sno | start date time | stop date time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-08-22 19:59:00.123 | 2023-08-22 20:15:00.013 |
| 2 | 2023-08-23 21:22:00.823 | 2023-08-23 21:29:00.823 |

Comment: Sample data is great, but perhaps a little less would do fine too? I get lost when I have to scroll page after page. ([mcve])

Comment: Do you mean 10 rows or 10 minutes? Or Either?

Comment: Question has been updated with the less data @jarlh ..

Comment: yes @PeterClemmensen each row = a minute Btw the constant has now been changed from 10 to 3 as i have reduced the data

Comment: So at Sno = 24, the meter has stopped because there are more than 10 minutes (not rows) from 2023-08-22 20:15:00.013 to 2023-08-23 21:22:00.823 where value is constant at 10849, correct?

Comment: In your original data, is there always one row per minute?

Comment: yes @PeterClemmensen correct

Comment: So at Sno = 24, the meter has stopped because there are more than 10 minutes (not rows) from 2023-08-22 20:15:00.013 to 2023-08-23 21:22:00.823 where value is constant at 10849, correct?   i have changed the data the generator started the next day... it should check for 10 minutes if the value remain same for 10 minutes it should get the time when value stop changing (the very first of 10849)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t;

CREATE TABLE #t
(
   Sno       INT 
 , TIMESTAMP DATETIME
 , VALUE     INT
)
;

INSERT INTO #t (Sno, TIMESTAMP, VALUE)
VALUES
  (1,  '2023-08-22 19:56:00.010', 10837)
, (2,  '2023-08-22 19:57:00.013', 10837)
, (3,  '2023-08-22 19:58:00.010', 10837)
, (4,  '2023-08-22 19:59:00.123', 10840)
, (5,  '2023-08-22 20:00:00.347', 10840)
, (6,  '2023-08-22 20:01:00.563', 10841)
, (7,  '2023-08-22 20:02:00.953', 10842)
, (8,  '2023-08-22 20:03:00.007', 10842)
, (9,  '2023-08-22 20:04:00.003', 10843)
, (10, '2023-08-22 20:05:00.017', 10843)
, (11, '2023-08-22 20:06:00.007', 10844)
, (12, '2023-08-22 20:07:00.000', 10844)
, (13, '2023-08-22 20:08:00.017', 10845)
, (14, '2023-08-22 20:09:00.003', 10845)
, (15, '2023-08-22 20:10:00.030', 10846)
, (16, '2023-08-22 20:11:00.017', 10846)
, (17, '2023-08-22 20:12:00.013', 10847)
, (22, '2023-08-22 20:13:00.020', 10848)
, (23, '2023-08-22 20:14:00.010', 10848)
, (24, '2023-08-22 20:15:00.013', 10849)
, (25, '2023-08-22 20:16:00.093', 10849)
, (26, '2023-08-22 20:17:00.297', 10849)
, (27, '2023-08-22 20:18:00.557', 10849)
, (28, '2023-08-23 21:22:00.823', 10849)
, (29, '2023-08-23 21:23:00.823', 10850)
, (30, '2023-08-23 21:24:00.823', 10851)
, (31, '2023-08-23 21:25:00.823', 10852)
, (32, '2023-08-23 21:26:00.823', 10853)
, (33, '2023-08-23 21:27:00.823', 10854)
, (34, '2023-08-23 21:28:00.823', 10854)
, (35, '2023-08-23 21:29:00.823', 10855)
, (36, '2023-08-23 21:30:00.823', 10855)
, (37, '2023-08-23 21:31:00.823', 10855)
, (38, '2023-08-23 21:32:00.823', 10855)
, (39, '2023-08-23 21:33:00.823', 10855)
, (40, '2023-08-23 21:34:00.823', 10855)
;


WITH C1 AS
(
SELECT *
     , DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY VALUE) AS s
     , CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY VALUE) < 5 THEN 0
       ELSE 1 end as flag
FROM #t
), C2 AS
(
SELECT *
     , IIF(LAG(flag, 1, -1) OVER (ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) <> flag, 1, 0) as ChangeFlag
FROM C1
WHERE S > 1
), C3 AS
(
SELECT *
     , SUM(CASE WHEN flag = 1 THEN 0 ELSE ChangeFlag END ) OVER (ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) AS IslandGroup
FROM C2
)

SELECT MIN(TIMESTAMP) AS StartDateTime
     , MAX(TIMESTAMP) AS EndDateTime
FROM (SELECT MIN(TIMESTAMP) AS TIMESTAMP, VALUE, IslandGroup
      FROM C3
      GROUP BY VALUE, IslandGroup) AS S
GROUP BY IslandGroup
;
```

**Result:**

```
StartDateTime            EndDateTime
2023-08-22 19:59:00.123  2023-08-22 20:15:00.013
2023-08-23 21:23:00.823  2023-08-23 21:29:00.823
```

Comment: brilliant I must say .. thanks alot @PeterClemmensen